# Pytezos balance_of entrypoint function for fa2 tokens

Tags: smartpy, pytezos

I was trying to implement a balance_of function. According to the documentation, it should be looking like this

```
$balance_of:
        {
          "requests": [ $requests_item, … ],
          "callback": contract ($callback_param)
        }

$callback_param:
        list (pair (pair %request (address %owner) (nat %token_id)) (nat %balance))

$requests_item:
        {
          "owner": address,
          "token_id": nat
        }
```

While Implementing i got stuck at the "callback": contract ($callback_param) because I cant figure out, what I have to place there.
Currently I have this:

```
my_contract.balance_of([{

        "requests": [{
            "owner": 'tzxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            "token_id": 0
        }],
        "callback": 

}])
```

What exactly do I have to fill in there?

Comment: Just set it to `None` https://pytezos.org/quick_start.html#view-method

Comment: Do you want to fetch the balance of someone? If that's the case, then use off-chain views or some indexer instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the answer that you're expecting, but I guess you should still give it a read.

The `balance_of` entrypoint is a view entrypoint as described in this [Deprecated TZIP](https://tzip.tezosagora.org/proposal/tzip-4/#view-entrypoints)
So, it is mostly used when you want to fetch someone's balance from another contract. In that case, your contract will call this `balance_of` entrypoint of the token contract, and the token contract will call back to your contract's `callback` entrypoint with the balance value.

Here is an example, taken from [SmartPy legacy docs](https://legacy.smartpy.io/docs/general/views#on-chain-views)
[image]

If you want to fetch balances off-chain. You can use indexers like [TzKt Token API](https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Tokens_GetTokenBalances) or [off-chain views](https://pytezos.org/quick_start.html#view-method). FA2 contracts can have a `get_balance` off-chain view, as described in [TZIP-12](https://tzip.tezosagora.org/proposal/tzip-12/#contract-metadata-tzip-016).

Note: If you're using off-chain views make sure that it is present in the contract. You can check that by going to the VIEWS tab of better call dev.

Comment: It should not be considered an onchain view anymore as there is now a separate concept for onchain views. Can you fix your message?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)
I've updated it.